# How to convert data frame to dictionary the call the api?

Tags: python, dataframe

How to convert dataframe to dictionary the call the api?

I have a data frame which is below

```
userid  url
123 x.com
345 y.com
```

```
{{'userid':'123','url':x.com'}{'userid':'345','url':y.com'}}
```

My api on first call

```
{
"userid": "123",
"data": {
"url": "x.com",
}
}
```

On second call

```
{
"userid": "345",
"data": {
"url": "y.com",
}
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to convert data frame to dictionary the and call the api after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the api does the following:

```
def create_dict(row):
   return {"userid" : row.userid ,"data": {"url": row.url}
```

you can pass df as follows:

```
results = df.apply(lambda row: create_dict(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'userid'", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I can understand you correctly, but you want to transform a `DataFrame` object to `dict`. From the official documentation, pandas has a method called `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()` , see it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)